# Ubislate 7 C+ is not visible while running android appliaction in ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have a new device with android 4.2.2 . I want to run android application on through ADT(Android Developer Tool) But when  I run application from ADT then this device is not detected . 
How ever USB debugging is ON.
and other android devices are working correctly.
 please help why this is so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the USB Vendor ID of the device in `0x0000` format to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` (or `%USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini` in Windows) and restart `adb`

To update `adb_usb.ini` with Vendor IDs of all currently connected `ADB` devices in Windows - run the following commands:

```
powershell "gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice | %{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | ?{$_.CompatibleID -like \"USB\Class_ff^&SubClass_42^&Prot_0?\"} | %{write \"0x$([regex]::match($_.deviceid.tolower(), 'vid_(\w+)').groups[1].value)\"} | sort -u" >> %USERPROFILE%\.android\adb_usb.ini
adb kill-server
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do ?

Comment: which OS are you using?